# How can I export a piece of a DOCX file and keep the same paragraph numbering?

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, word-addins

#### TL;DR:

How can I capture the paragraph numbering as a 'part' of the text and export it to a DOCX?

---

### Problem

I have a document that's split into sections and sub-sections that reads similarly to a set of state statutes (`Statute 208`, with subsections `Statute 208.1`, `Statute 208.2`, etc.). We created this by modifying the `numbering.xml` file within the .docx zip.

I want to export a 'sub-section' (`208.5`) and its text to a separate .docx file. My VSTO add-in exports the text well enough, but the **numbering resets** to `208.1`. This does make some sense as it's now the first paragraph with that `<ilvl>` in the document.

#### PDF works okay

Funnily enough, I'm able to call `Word.Range`'s `ExportAsFixedFormat` function and export this selection to PDF just fine - even retaining the numbering. This led me down a path of trying to 'render' the selection, possibly as it would be printed, in order to throw it into a new .docx file, but I haven't figured that out, either.

---

### What I've tried:

- `Range.ExportFragment()` using both `wdFormatStrictOpenXMLDocument` and `wdFormatDocumentDefault`as the `wdSaveType` values.

  - These export but also reset the numbering.
- `Document.PrintOut()` using `PrintToFile = true` and a valid filename. I realize now that this, quite literally, generates 'printout instructions' and won't inject a new file at path `filename` with any valid file structure.

  - Plainly doesn't work. :)
- `Application.Selection.XML` to a variable `content` and calling `Document.Content.InsertXML(content)` on a newly added Document object.

  - Still resets the numbering.

---

### Code Section for Context

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

Word.Range range = Application.ActiveDocument.Range(startPosition, endPosition);
range.Select();

//export to DOCX?
Application.Selection.Range.ExportFragment(
    filename, Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatDocumentDefault);
```

Comment: Can you please try setting Range.ListFormat.ListLevelNumber to see if that helps?

Comment: @Jazimov The `ListLevelNumber` is `1`, and I think that's because it's a top-level 'section' (domain term).. however, I do see `ListString` under `ListLevelNumber` as well, and that's got the `208.5` that I'm talking about.. Maybe when I export that content, I can set the `ListLevelString` after the fact.. giving that a shot.

Comment: Excellent! Let us all know if your idea ended up working.

Comment: That find led me to `ListValue`, representing the 'index' of the List object within the list.. that would have worked too, but it only has a getter - no setter. Next, I found the `ListFormat.ConvertNumbersToText()` method. That worked!! ... but, I haven't yet found how to un-convert the original text..

Comment: Did you try to set ListLevelNumber? It's read/write.

Comment: Also, take a look at the ListLevel object's StartAt property: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.listlevel.startat

Comment: ListLevelNumber modifies the indent level, whereas I'm looking for the 'rendered' value of the indent level, itself. So far, still operating with trying to 'undo' the effects of `ListFormat.ConvertNumbersToText()` in the starting document. 

As for ListLevel.. It looks like the current `ListTemplate` has the collection of `ListLevels` with which I could access the `StartAt` property. If only I could figure out which Template is currently 'in effect'..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use ConvertNumbersToText(wdNumberAllNumbers) before exporting, then `_Document.Undo()` or close without saving after the export.

Comment: Good call on `ConvertNumbersToText()`! Closing without saving isn't an option per my business rules, but how can I undo? That's the part I'm stuck on at the moment.

Comment: That's as simple as ActiveDocument.Undo.

Comment: Good find - unfortunately, after testing this, it looks like the `ConvertNumbersToText()` method doesn't actually get registered as an 'undoable' action. I verified this by getting rid of the `Undo()` call I'd placed and checking both that the Undo 'dropdown' is empty and that 'undoing' does nothing.

Comment: ActiveDocument.ConvertNumbersToText (wdNumberParagraph), later followed by ActiveDocument.Undo works for me. I suspect wdNumberAllNumbers was the wrong parameter in this case - the other parameter you might try is wdNumberListNum. In any case, why can't you close the original document without saving after generating the output?

Comment: In short, because business rules require it. In 'long', this is a part of a method that programmatically exports one chunk of the document to a separate docx file, but the users want the original document to stay open.

Comment: I found my issue with `Undo()`. Part of this scenario includes Unprotecting the document, grabbing the XML of the currently selected portion, and re-protecting the document. Something about `Protect()`/`Unprotect()` was, I'm guessing, clearing the `Undo()` cache.

Comment: `cont.` - Document Protection recently left our requirements, so I'm now able to use the `Undo()` command after `ConvertNumbersToText()`, making this the accepted answer. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

There is some good information at this (dated) link that still should work with current Word APIs:
https://forums.windowssecrets.com/showthread.php/27711-Determining-which-ListTemplates-item-is-in-use-(VBA-Word-2000)

Information at that link suggests that you can create a name/handle for your ListTemplate so that you can reference it in code--as long as your statute-style bullets are associated with a named style for the document. The idea is to first name the ListTemplate that's associated with the statute bullet style for the active document and then reference that name when accessing the ListLevels collection.

For instance, you could have code that looks something like this:

`ActiveDocument.Styles("StatutesBulletStyle").ListTemplate.Name = "StatuteBulletListTemplate";`

After the above assignment, you can refer to the template by name:

`ActiveDocument.ListTemplates("StatuteBulletListTemplate").ListLevels(1).StartAt = 5;`

Using the above technique no longer requires that you try to figure out what the active template is...

Does that help?

Comment: Ah, interesting.. hmm. But how do I name the `Style` in the first place? I think the logic for our numbering scheme is in the `numbering.xml` file.. I can get that modified to have a `<name>` or `<id>` tag if that's what one does.

Comment: I can see that working though.. if I can get ahold of the template, I can probably make that the template for the exported document (which takes over the role of being the `Application.ActiveDocument` in our case).

Comment: If you hit Ctrl+Shift+S over text that's in your numbered sections, you should be able to see the style that's currently applied to that section. It might just be "Normal". If that fails, you should experiment with defining a style [out of scope here] and applying that to your document or to sections that are numbered as you describe. Without knowing the specifics of your total document, you at least should be able to leverage knowing what you're currently using as a style, and try to grab the current ListTemplate from that style name using the strategy above.

Comment: It did turn out to be the "Normal" `Style`. I've got a handle on it via `Application.ActiveDocument.Style["Normal"]` (this is c#). However, the `ListTemplate` property is null.. still researching.